# I have a CS0103 error on my InitializeComponent()

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

im coding a C# windows console hang man program. i have a main form called Form1 that has a partial class called Form1 where the InitializeComponent() error is and in a different file i have another partial class called HangCode that inherits from Form1 where all the code for the progam is

[image]

Ive tried writing all the code with in the Form1 , commenting out the error , removing the inheritance of the HangCode and everything VS has suggested

Comment: Did code ever work? What changed since last time worked.  IntializeComponent uses the designer.cs file.  Sometimes this error occurs if the namespace in the partial class is not the same as the main class.  Does both the main class and partial class inherit the same base class?

Comment: "im coding a C# windows console hang man program" - that doesn't look like a *console* application. It looks like Windows Forms. In what way is it a console app?

Comment: It wouldn't entirely surprise me if this were some artifact of an unusual project name. I suggest you just call it "Hangman" rather than "Hangman1.0" - a namespace of `Hangman1._0` feels more likely to cause problems then benefits.

Comment: Can't tell from just that screenshot - is `InitializeComponent` defined in Form1.Designer.cs? Is the Form1 in that file in the same namespace as Form1.cs?

Comment: @DStanley yes it is in the same namespace as Form1.cs and yes it is defined in Form1.Designer.Cs

Comment: @JonSkeet okay ill rename the project to Hangman

Comment: @JonSkeet oh yes it is a Windows form

Comment: @jdweng yes it did work a while back I first coded it on VS 2012 a few years ago and I decided to code it again using VS 2022..  so i just checked the Form1.Designer.cs file and the partial class there doesnt seem to have any inheritance

Comment: Did you copy the designer.cs from old project?  Usually when I modify an old Form project I create a new Form project.  Then copy old designer file contents to new project making sure the namespace and class for the designer file matches new project.

Comment: @jdweng no i didnt copy the designer.cs form ,, let me start a new project and do what you suggest

Comment: @jdweng I started a new program making sure the namespaces are the same and that the classes inherit from the same base class and the error is gone Thank you !!